# In order to mock objects, shall we declare all member functions virtual(C++)?

Tags: c++, performance, googletest, virtual-functions, googlemock

Virtual functions have costs during runtime. But without virtual function, we can not mock objects to do unit test.

What is the best practice of this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But without virtual function, we can not mock objects to do unit test.

That's not completely true. As from the [Google Mock Cookbook](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/v1_5/CookBook.md#mocking-nonvirtual-methods) you actually can mock non-virtual functions:

> One way to do it is to templatize your code that needs to use a packet stream. More specifically, you will give your code a template type argument for the type of the packet stream. In production, you will instantiate your template with ConcretePacketStream as the type argument. In tests, you will instantiate the same template with MockPacketStream. For example, you may write:
>
> ```
> template <class PacketStream>
> void CreateConnection(PacketStream* stream) { ... }
>
> template <class PacketStream>
> class PacketReader {
>  public:
>   void ReadPackets(PacketStream* stream, size_t packet_num);
>  };
> ```
>
> Then you can use `CreateConnection<ConcretePacketStream>()` and `PacketReader<ConcretePacketStream>` in production code, and use `CreateConnection<MockPacketStream>()` and `PacketReader<MockPacketStream>` in tests.
>
> ```
>  MockPacketStream mock_stream;
>  EXPECT_CALL(mock_stream, ...)...;
>  ... set more expectations on mock_stream ...
>   PacketReader<MockPacketStream> reader(&mock_stream);
>  ... exercise reader ...
> ```

Comment: Nothing good comes out of google in terms of dev support stuff. Their coding guidelines are terrible, and you just showed me how their mock library is terrible (which I always suspected, but never actually looked at).

Comment: @SergeyA Well, you have the choice of dynamic or static polymorphism. That's what's going on in real life code.

Comment: I am not denying this. But the unit test library which mandates polymorphism (of one sort or another) where my original design doesn't require one is just a bad library.

Comment: @SergeyA So your designs don't use any interface contracts in 1st place?

Comment: My designs follow the requirement of the application, not unit-testing library. If polymoprhism is not needed, it is not there.

Comment: @SergeyA If there's no polymorphism or interface contract, there's probably no need to mock a class, but just use it regularly, or just give it a thin wrapper to keep track of expected calls.